# Why keras showing Could not compute output KerasTensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

So, I have 3 models, say A,B and C. so, say a_input= b_outpur and b_input= a_output. c_input= (a_input+b_input) Now, I want to add A to C to make a model, and again B to C to make another model. But, the model.add is showing "Could not compute output KerasTensor".

```
t1= keras.layers.Input(shape=(LATENT_DIM, ) )
t1_model= keras.models.Model(t1, t1)
concated= keras.layers.merge.concatenate([t1, g_out])
model_x= keras.models.Model([g_in, t1], concated)

model_x.compile(optimizer= 'Adam', loss='MSE')

ip= np.ones(3)
ip= ip.reshape(-1, 1)
op= np.ones(6)
op= op.reshape(-1,2)


model_x.fit([ip,ip], [ip,op])


model_x.summary()

model= keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(model_x)
model.add(d_model)
```

the **model.add(model_x)** is showing

```
AssertionError: Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='concatenate_48/concat:0', description="created by layer 'concatenate_48'")
```

This is the summary of model_x

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)                 (None, 300)          600         input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_43 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)                (None, 2)            602         dense_9[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_48 (Concatenate)    (None, 3)            0           input_43[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_10[0][0]
```

Please help... I am soo confused since 2 days...

P.S. I have used some dummy data to check if model is being trained.

Comment: `inputs` and `outputs` cannot be the same Layer for `Model`.

Comment: Hey @Shubham, model X has hidden layers as well as the model t1 concatinated.. when training, the paremeters of the hidden layers are being updated, t1 is like a placeholder to be used as input in the next model which i need to concatinate... The model_x is training with the dummy data as well... just that, I cant add model_x to model...